# NSURLConnection sends incomplete string

Tags: iphone

How can i check whether NSURLConnection is sending the whole request string to the webserver or not? 
I am calling one webservice in which length of request string varies. 
When i send small request string, the webservice is working fine. 
But when the request string length is long, the webservice is not giving me proper response.

Has anyone faced such a problem?

Comment: is everything urlencoded? e.g. - (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I was sending & sign in the string. Web service was not able to handle it.